# UPDATE Query Without WHERE Clause doesn;t work

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm getting in this strange situation.. I'm trying to execute and update query without where clause.. Here is the query

```
UPDATE `siteconfig` 
SET `homepagereview` = 'Justine Pope, London', 
`homepagetitle1` = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 
`homepagecontent1` = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'
```

when I execute the query, it doesn't do anything at all.. I also inserted a row with NULL values and executed this update query but still nothing happens..!

Here is the table structre...

```
CREATE TABLE `siteconfig` (
    `homepagereview` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `googleadsensecode` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `analyticscode` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `sliderimage1` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `sliderimage2` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `sliderimage3` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `homepagetitle1` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `homepagecontent1` VARCHAR(1000) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `homepagetitle2` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `homepagecontent2` VARCHAR(1000) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
)
COMMENT='misc settings for website'
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using, and why are you using backticks?

Comment: How do you execute the wuery? Maybe the issue is not related to the UPDATE statement. Are you committing after executing the SQL? When your table is huge it may produce a huge log and attain size limitations and do a rollback. How much time dies the UPDATE take?

Comment: If I recall correctly there is some setting in MySQL to prevent DML without a WHERE clause. But I don't remember the name of the setting.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. You're right - it's called "Safe updates" and you can't update without referencing the PK. If you are using e.g. MySQL Workbench you can turn it off in Edit/Preferences/SQL Editor/Query Editor/Clear "Safe Updates" checkbox.

Comment: @Lord Peter, @ a_horse_with_no_name: i need to execute it using php mysql_query() function..! I've ended up using PK in table.. until i don't find any solution.

Comment: You will have to change the my.cnf file on your server and comment out the safe-updates setting in the [mysql] section. (It's there to prevent clumsy things like "delete from table" deleting all your data.) If you are happy deleting using a where clause on the PK then you can just leave it set.

Answer (score 1):

You can prepend you code with:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
```

When `SQL_SAFE_UPDATES` is 1 you are not allowed to perform `UPDATE` or `DELETE` commands on a table without specifying key column. This is done basically to save user from accidentally wiping out table data in case she forgets to add `WHERE` clause.